Telerik Kendo MVC TabStrip - how to set focus when loading a partial view
I have a Kendo tabstrip with partial views. When I click on the tab, the partial views are loaded.  But I need to set the focus() and/or tabindex to a specific element in the partial view, for example the first text box. I tried setting the tabindex to 1 in the partial view. But that does Not seem to work.
There seems to be 2 TabStrip methods for loading a partial views ?
.LoadContentFrom("CustomerEdit"...
and
.Content(@<text> @Html.Partial("OrdersEdit"
I think the LoadContentFrom is Ajax.
Using Content(@<text> @Html.Partial("OrdersEdit"**... how can I set the focus to my first textbox on the the OrdersEdit.. I tried setting tabindex =1 and tried this:
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#firstTextBox').focus();
}

But does not work.
Any ideas?

I think you need to handle the activate event on the tab strip which is triggered after a tab is being made visible and its animation complete. The event data should give you the activated tab and its content element. From that you should be able to find the first input element in the tab and call focus on it.
